# Rails: How to check for attributes with polymorphic? (Prints okay, won't allow conditional)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, methods, conditional-statements

Going back to accessing user attributes (name, e-mail, avatar, etc) for the comments section ("identify user as commenter"), why does it let me print out some values but not use them in conditionals?

Why can I do this? (Prints the avatar next to the comment as it should)

`<%= image_tag comment.user.avatar.url, size: "64" %>`

But not this? (Won't let me check if there's an avatar or not first)

`<% if comment.user.avatar.url.empty/blank/nil/present? %>`

So if a commenter hasn't uploaded an avatar yet, it returns:

`undefined method \'avatar\' for nil:NilClass`

Is there a method I need to define in a controller, or a scope in a model, or is there another way of checking in this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: In the case you are using `if comment.user.avatar`, `comment` does not have an `user`, thus no `avatar`. Is it a different case from the usage of `image_tag`?

Comment: It's the same comment and user, in theory.

Comment: Can you check before the `if` if `comment.user.present?`. Also, is `comment` persisted? Maybe you have not initialized the user yet. Also, you're breaking Demeter's Law here, I'd suggest you refactor this code. Bugs will be easier to smash ;)

Comment: Very strange. It does let me do this, though, which is a solution of sorts for now: `<%= image_tag comment.user.avatar.url, size: "64" unless comment.user.blank? %>`.

Comment: Makes sense to check for that if user can be blank ;)

Comment: :-) Not really, but have been deleting/adding users lots of times today to test the sign-up process. So there are some article with comments where the user has disappeared. But makes me wonder what would happen to page rendering if a user was deleted in real application. Either leave his comments there with no username or delete his comments when you delete him. Hmmmm.

Comment: That's why I was refering to Demeter's Law before. You could create a presenter class for comment (do you know https://github.com/drapergem/draper?) and get the avatar like this `CommentDecorator.new(comment).user_avatar_image`. There you define the case for comments with no user, with user and such. And you may also consider if you prefer to delete the comment on user deletion. `User has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy` in that case ...